# MATLAB Solving equations problem

Tags: matlab, equations

I want to solve these equations using [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) and **I am sure** there is a non zero solution. The equations are:

```
0.7071*x            + 0.7071*z = x 
  -0.5*x + 0.7071*y +    0.5*z = y
  -0.5*x - 0.7071*y +    0.5*z = z
```

I wrote in MATLAB:

```
[x,y,z]=solve('0.7071 * x+0.7071 * z=x','-0.5 * x+0.7071 * y+0.5 * z=y','-0.5 * x-0.7071 * y+0.5 * z=z');
```

But the result is x = y = z = 0.
As I said I am sure that there is a solution. Can any one help?

Comment: As the first equation is lacking y it should not be difficult to find the solution by hand. What do you get?

Comment: +/- signs wouldn't have any effect.

Comment: @Hani: Why are you sure there is a non-zero solution?

Comment: ...because it's a rotation matrix of the first kind. As such it has an eigenvector for the eigenvalue of 1. This eigenvector is the rotation axis and a nontrivial solution.

Comment: MuPAD also says the solution is x=y=z=0, when I ask it to find solutions assuming x<> 0, it just give me the empty solution.

Comment: @Lasse: The problem is accuracy. If you substitute 0.7071 with sqrt(0.5) one of the nontrivial solutions is x=1, y=-1, z=sqrt(2)-1. To be fair, the equation system he mentioned is not singular due to this (possible) inaccuracy, but only "almost singular". See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for a non-trivial solution v to A*v=v with v=[x;y;z] and...

```
A =
   0.70710678118655                  0   0.70710678118655
  -0.50000000000000   0.70710678118655   0.50000000000000
  -0.50000000000000  -0.70710678118655   0.50000000000000
```

You can transform this into (A-I)v=0 where I is the 3x3 identity matrix. What you have to do to find a nontrivial solution is checking the null space of A-I:

```
>> null(A-eye(3))

ans =

   0.67859834454585
  -0.67859834454585
   0.28108463771482
```

So, you have a onedimensional nullspace. Otherwise you'd see more than one column. Every linear combination of the columns is a point in this null space that A-I maps to the null vector. So, every multiple of this vector is a solution to your problem.

Actually, your matrix A is a rotation matrix of the first kind because det(A)=1 and A'*A=identity. So it has an eigenvalue of 1 with the rotation axis as corresponding eigenvector. The vector I computed above is the normalized rotation axis.

Note: For this I replaced your 0.7071 with sqrt(0.5). If rounding errors are a concern but you know in advance that there has to be a nontrivial solution the best bet is to do a singular value decomposition of A-I and pick the right most right singular vector:

```
>> [u,s,v] = svd(A-eye(3));
>> v(:,end)

ans =

   0.67859834454585
  -0.67859834454585
   0.28108463771482
```

This way you can calculate a vector v that minimizes |A*v-v| under the constraint that |v|=1 where |.| is the Euclidean norm.

Comment: Thank you very much this is what exactly i want but frankly i could not understand how did you get it.Please could you advice me with a reference which describes this idea (not a fully Linear algebra book but only this idea ex: A chapter or a section from a book).

Comment: What exactly is it that you don't understand?

Comment: The null space, eigenvalue . Why A-I gives result although it is multiplied by v (A-I)v=0. I read what null function do in matlab but i could not understand it exactly. Why did you took the v only from svd result and what u and s represents. I really appreciate your description and your time spent to explain, but the problem lies beyond the fact that i learnt linear Algebra with out going deep in these topics and i dont have time now(just now) to read a full book for linear Algebra. With my grateful. Hani Almousli..

Comment: Forget about null. The important thing you should understand is what the SVD is and what the properties of these 3 matrices are. I suggest you do a little research on this topic on your own. Wikipedia is a good start, I suppose.

Comment: Basically you're computing the eigenvectors of the matrix A : AX=lambda*X with lambda=1. `[V D] = eig(A)` and pick the vector `V(:,3)` corresponding to the real eigenvalue 1 `D(3,3)`. This page is might have some explanations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue,_eigenvector_and_eigenspace

Comment: Another alternative for computing an eigenvector v for a given matrix A and eigenvalue lambda: `[Q,R]=qr(A'-lambda*eye(size(A))); v=Q(:,end)`. For 3x3 rotation matrices there is an even easier way to compute the rotation axis, though.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you need to use the `solve` function as your equations is a system of linear equations.

Recast as a matrix equation:

```
Ax = B
```

In your case:

```
    | -0.2929   0.0      0.7071  |  | x |     | 0 |
    | -0.5     -0.2929   0.5     |  | y |  =  | 0 |
    | -0.5     -0.7071  -0.5     |  | z |     | 0 |
```

Use the built-in functionally of MATLAB to solve it. See e.g. [MATLAB: Solution of Linear Systems of Equations](http://clipper.lehigh.edu/engr1/notes/MATLABsystemsSolution.htm).

The core of MATLAB is to solve this kind of equation.

---

Using [FreeMat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeMat) (an open-source MATLAB-like environment with
a GPL license; [direct download URL](http://garr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/freemat/FreeMat4/FreeMat-4.0-win32.exe) for Windows installer):

```
   A = [ -0.2929 0.0 0.7071; -0.5 -0.2929 0.5; -0.5 -0.7071 -0.5 ]

   B = [0.0; 0.0; 0.0]

   A\B

   ans =
    0
    0
    0
```

So the solution is: x = 0, y = 0,  z = 0

---

The solution can also be derived by hand. Starting from the last two equations:

```
    -0.5*x + 0.7071*y +    0.5*z = y
    -0.5*x - 0.7071*y +    0.5*z = z

    0.2929*y =  -0.5*x + 0.5*z
    0.7071*y =  -0.5*x + 0.5*z

    0.2929*y = 0.7071*y
```

Thus y = 0.0 and:

```
    0.7071*y =  -0.5*x + 0.5*z

    0 =  -0.5*x + 0.5*z

    0 =  -0.5*x + 0.5*z

    0.5*x = 0.5*z

    x = z
```

Inserting in the first equation:

```
    0.7071*x + 0.7071*z = x 

    0.7071*x + 0.7071*x = x 

    1.4142*x = x
```

Thus x = 0.0. And as x = z, then z = 0.0.

Comment: I wrote A=[0.7071 0 0.7071;-0.5 0.7071 0.5; -0.5 -0.7071 0.5]<br/>
[x;y;z]=A*[x;y;z]<br/>
but it gives error. Note that the right hand side are x,y,z not zeros.Please could you write it in Matlab for me.

Comment: I have updated the question with code that should run in MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks for your interest but the B array should be [x;y;z] and the equation you wrote are not like the equations which i wrote in the questions.

Comment: -1 You messed up somewhere. There *is* a nontrivial solution. In fact, there are infinitely many because the matrix T of your Tv=0 system is singular.

Answer (score 0):

x = 0, y = 0, z = 0 is the correct solution. This problem can be easily worked by hand.

Comment: It is A solution. It is NOT the solution desired by the question. Null gives the non-trivial solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
A = [ 0.7071 0 0.7071 ;
      -0.5 0.7071 0.5 ;
    -0.5 -0.7071 0.5 ];
B = [1 ; 1 ; 1];

AA = A-diag(B)

      -0.2929            0       0.7071
         -0.5      -0.2929          0.5
         -0.5      -0.7071         -0.5

BB = B-B

     0
     0
     0

AA\BB

     0
     0
     0
```

Answer (score -1):

Friends use MATLAB command rref(A) for Ax=B.... It will give a upper triangular Matrix. Then u can calculate non-trivial solutions easily... But keep in mind that if rref(A)=I (as in your case) then non-trivial solutions do not exist. 
BEST OF LUCK