# Solving system of equations using matlab

Tags: matlab, system, equations

So I have the following system of equations

```
 x1 - x2 =  20
 x2 - x3 =  30
 x3 - x4 =  75
 x4 - x5 = -49
-x1 + x5 = -20
```

how would I solve the system using Matlab? I I'm a little stuck.

There's a good chance there's no solution but if someone could let me know how to do it that would be great!

Comment: Here's a hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728636/matlab-solving-equations-problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, convert this equation into matrix notation:

```
A = [ 1 -1  0  0  0
      0  1 -1  0  0
      0  0  1 -1  0
      0  0  0  1 -1
     -1  0  0  0  1];

b = [ 20
      30
      75
     -49
     -20];
```

You are trying to find `x` giving `Ax = b`. You can not take the inverse of `A` since it is singular. To see this check its rank; `rank(A) == 4`. It would be 5 if `A` were non-singular.

So, you should find best `x` approximating `b` when multiplied by `A` from left. This is an optimization problem: you want to minimize the error between `Ax` and `b`. Usually, people use least squares method. That is, you minimize the sum of squares of the residuals. This can be done by [pseudo inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Linear_least-squares) as follows:

```
x = pinv(A) * b
```

gives

```
x =

   31.8000
   23.0000
    4.2000
  -59.6000
    0.6000
```

Best approximation is found by

```
b2 = A*x


b2 =

    8.8000
   18.8000
   63.8000
  -60.2000
  -31.2000
```

The least squares error is found to be

```
e = norm(b-b2)

e =

   25.0440
```

If you want to try other methods alternative to least squares to minimize `Ax-b`, you can google l1-minimization, sparse encoding, etc.

Comment: Telling people to test for singularity by use of det is a terribly poor idea. Better is to suggest the use of rank or cond. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145948/how-to-find-out-if-a-matrix-is-singular/13146750#13146750

Comment: And now an answer I can agree with. +1

Answer (score 0):

Just look at it and mentally add up the equations.  LHS is zero, right hand side is something positive, so there is no solution!